# C++ take a user input as the number of dimensions an array has?

Tags: c++, arrays, dimensions, declare

I can't seem to find anything regarding whether or not this is possible. Ideally I'd have someone input an integer like "4" and then it would make a 4-d array.

is this at all possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  What have you tried?

Comment: When you say a "4-d array" what do you actually mean? An array with 4 elements or something which is accessed as `array[n0][n1][n2][n3]`? While the former is possible, I don't think the latter is possible in C++. Other programming languages may allow a dynamic specification of dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the Stack Overflow post, "[Create an N dimensional array, where N is determined at runtime (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334952/create-an-n-dimensional-array-where-n-is-determined-at-runtime-c)":

```
The dimensions of an array are part of the type, and the type must be known 
at compile time.
```

Thus the programmer must specify the dimensions of the array before [`compile-time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compile_time), not during [`run-time`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run_time_(program_lifecycle_phase)).

[`Type checking`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Type_checking) is typically one of the first operations a compiler does (it is specifically found in the [`semantic analysis`](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs143/cs143.1128/handouts/180%20Semantic%20Analysis.pdf) portion of the compiler's control flow) to ensure the code received is free of simple programming errors (assignment/equivilance errors, etc).

Please let me know if you have any questions!